# Rails 5 JSON API puts (and patch) with relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

We are looking to save JSON API puts with Rails 5 (we are using ember.js on the front end).

We are struggling to work out the best way to save/create relationship data.

Our model:

```
class ProductSpec < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organisation
end
```

Our serializer:

```
class ProductSpecSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
  has_one :organisation
end
```

Our controller:

```
class ProductSpecsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product_spec, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  {...}

  # PATCH/PUT /product_specs/1
  def update
    if @product_spec.update(product_spec_params)
      render json: @product_spec
    else
      render json: @product_spec.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

{...}
  private
    def set_product_spec
      @product_spec = ProductSpec.find(params[:id])
    end

    def product_spec_params
      params.require(:data)
        .require(:attributes)
        .permit(
          :name
        )
    end
 end
```

And our JSON

```
Parameters: {"data"=>{"id"=>"7", "attributes"=>{"name"=>"Tester"}, "relationships"=>{"organisation"=>{"data"=>{"type"=>"organisations", "id"=>"1"}}}, "type"=>"product-specs"}, "id"=>"7", "product_spec"=>{}}
```

Any changes to name are nicely saved. The question how to best design our controller so that we save the 'organisation' relationship (realise that we also have to permit this, too).